Selling non-kosher food
May a vending machine owner sell non-kosher food in the vending machine?
The location is a general place like a park or a rehab center etc.
Also what about chamezt on Pesach, is the owner obligated to remove the chametz items from the vending machine?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25661/jewish-person-selling-non-kosher-product

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27999/to-what-extent-should-one-not-sell-unkosher-goods

Owning chametz has the additional dimension of בל יראה ובל ימצא.
